# ERROR: could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.5.so":

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37IjI.png)

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to add postgis as an extension in pgAdmin.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Linker Errors should first be checked.

1. Check if the `/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.5.so` Binary File really exists.
2. Check if the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` Environment Variable contains the `/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/postgresql` Folder.